# Attaching an entity of type 'ModelName" failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity to update a row in my database. My form return an Object that is supposed to update the old object that is stored in the DB. When I find out that the user left the password field blank, I want to keep the same old password value of the old object. Whenever I call the database asking for the old object, I hit the error when updating the object with Entity. I've tried all the AddOrUpdate, Attach, Detach stuff from Entity but nothing worked. Also, I can't do Delete then Add because the OldConnector has an incremental Id on the table that I can't modify. Here's my code :

```
public void Update(Connector NewConnector)
    {
        {
            if (NewConnector.Password == "")
            {
                Connector OldConnector = _db.ConnectorsTable.Where(x => x.ID == NewConnector.ID).FirstOrDefault(); //Grabbing the old connectors password
                NewConnector.Password = OldConnector.Password;
            }
        }
        _db.Entry(NewConnector).State = EntityState.Modified; //Code Crashes here
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to attach `NewConnector` which has the same ID as `OldConnector`, that will never work.

Comment: @DavidG How do you think I can solve this? I just need to bring the password value of OldConnector and assign it to the password property of NewConnector.

Comment: Is `NewConnector` is a new entity to be added to the database?

Comment: @DavidG Yes. I just want to modify its Password Property though beofre I add it to the DB.

Comment: Then it needs an ID value that doesn't conflict with an existing one.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works cause this code works perfectly  `if (NewConnector.Password == "")
            {
                      NewConnector.Password = "JohnDoe";
            }`

Comment: `NewConnector.ID` is the same as `OldConnector.ID`, that means you cannot add the new entity to your database because the primary key is a duplicate.

Comment: If you don't load the old one, then you are simply going to overwrite the existing row in your database. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to update the existing row, with new values coming from the NewConnector object. I can do it fine when I am not grabbing the old password from the existing row in DB. As soon as I call the _db.Connectors, the code doesn't work anymore, even though at the end I'm still doing the same _db.Entry(NewConnector).State = EntityState.Modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework tracks objects you have loaded. So when you query the database for the `OldConnector` object, that item is kept in memory.

You then go on to try and save your `NewConnector` object which has the same primary key ID. Entity Framework checks it's internal state and finds a matching entity, that is why you get the error. Since you are trying to update the existing object, you should do this instead:

```
public void Update(Connector newConnector)
{
    if (newConnector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(newConnector));
    }

    var oldConnector = _db.ConnectorsTable
        .Where(x => x.ID == newConnector.ID)
        .Single(); //Grabbing the old connectors password

    if (newConnector.Password == "")
    {
        newConnector.Password = oldConnector.Password;
    }

    //Update the old entity with values from the new entity:
    _db.Entry(oldConnector).CurrentValues.SetValues(newConnector);
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I am hitting this exception now Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type 'Connector' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Connector>.

Comment: I can't believe it worked! Been stuck there for 2 days. Thank you sir!

Comment: But what if `newConnector` is `null`? It crashes. Code security should never need to be asked for, it should be the default way to write ALL code.

Comment: @DavidG But it's a valid argument.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Possibly, but the code I am adding is 'secure'. How OP uses it is up to them.

Comment: ...and `oldConnector` can't even be used in `Entry()` as it is defined in another scope. Flawed answer.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Good spot, I've fixed that for you. Also added a null check, thanks!